# Apache PDF Box call javascript inside document

Tags: javascript, apache, pdf, pdfbox

I ve been using Apache PDfBox 2.0.5. I would like to ask if there is a way to call a Javascript code located in the pdf document eg. in a text field ? I ve got an existing Pdf document that stores many Javascript snippets under it elements. I am able to fill up the data but then I need to call some snippets before closing the document.

Comment: PDFBox does not execute JavaScript.

Comment: If you know what the form is about, you'll have to find out and then implement yourself whatever the JS code is doing.

Comment: Thanks for your comments ! I know what the form is about or rather field inside a form. I know the js code inside and just want to call it while the pdf is being generated. Something like PDField myField ... then myFiled.runJS(method name) ...

Comment: Like mkl said, you can't. PDFBox doesn't have a JS interpreter. What I meant is that whatever the JS code does, you'll have to reverse engineer and implement in java. E.g. enable / fill / check some fields based on the values of other fields, or date checks, or formatting, whatever.

Comment: I thought there would be a way to run the js inside the pdf file from Java... I went throw the PdfBox API but could not find anything. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: If you are open to using another Java Toolkit, one does exist that will process forms the same way as Adobe Acrobat on the desktop. It will run all field validation and calculation scripts and update the PDF with their results.